# Umbraco razor macro DynamicPublishedContentList does not contain a definition for

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller, umbraco

My umbraco view has generated the following code for a macro that works fine:

```
@* Helper method to travers through all descendants *@
@helper Traverse(dynamic node)
{
    @* Update the level to reflect how deep you want the sitemap to go *@
    var maxLevelForSitemap = 5;

    @* Select visible children *@
    var selection = node.Children.Where("Visible").Where("Level <= " + maxLevelForSitemap);

    @* If any items are returned, render a list *@
    if (selection.Any())
    {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var page in selection)
            {
                <li class="level-@page.Level @(page.IsAncestorOrSelf(CurrentPage) ? "on" : null)">
                    @if (page.isNotNavigable == true)
                    {
                        <span>
                            <cite class="arrow"></cite>@page.Name
                        </span>
                    }
                    //if next line fails, add before the if below: page.HasProperty("pageRedirectTarget")
                    else if (page.HasValue("pageRedirectTarget"))
                    {
                        var redirectPage = Umbraco.Content(page.pageRedirectTarget);
                        <a href="@redirectPage.Url.Substring(0, redirectPage.Url.Length - 1)@page.pageRedirectComplement">
                            <cite class="arrow"></cite>@page.Name
                        </a>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <a href="@page.Url">
                            <cite class="arrow"></cite>@page.Name
                        </a>
                    }

                    @* Run the traverse helper again for any child pages *@
                    @Traverse(page)
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    }
}
```

The problem happens when I added another dll (compiled in 3.5 framework) and the **selection.Any()** stop working, instead gives an error saying "does not contain a definition for Any()".

I know that dynamic doens't support extension methods but why does it work without me adding the reference and with it gives the error?

Can anyone help me?

thanks.

Comment: What's the other dll in question? Also, I'd suggest using IPublishedContent instead of dynamic. e.g. Traverse(IPublishedContent node)

Comment: it's "custom made" butin .net 3.5 to be compatible with sharepoint 2007

Comment: Just wondering, have you tried "selection.Length() > 0"

Comment: as MrVentzi suggested above...try either .Length() or .Count() and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer, but too long for a comment and hopefully it will help in your troubleshooting.
Check for the following .dlls in your bin directory and delete them if you don't need them for your project.  Delete them one at a time and retest after each to see if you can nail it down.

> EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>  WebGrease.dll (delete and update to
>   latest)
>  DotNetOAuth.dll

This info came from the Umbraco forums and particularly the two posts linked below.

https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/45308-umbracoMacroEnginesDynamicNodeList-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-Random

https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/53022-UmbracoWebModelsDynamicPublishedContentList-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-Any